# How to force CLR run verification?

Tags: .net, clr, cil, type-safety

The code bellow passes over CLR verification (you can try assembling it with `ilasm.exe` and run the resulting `.exe` without any error -- I am testing it with CLR v4.0.30319).

However if you run `PEverify.exe` over the resulting `.exe` it will report an:

> Unexpected type on stack.

regarding the invalid object `Exception` that I am passing to `Console::WriteLine(string)` method.

Why is not CLR running verification? And, how can we force CLR to run it?

```
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
    .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )
    .ver 4:0:0:0
}

.assembly TypeSafe
{
}

.class TypeSafe
{
    .method static void Start()
    {
        .entrypoint
        ldstr       "Exception instead of String"
        newobj      instance void [mscorlib]System.Exception::.ctor(string)
        call        void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
        ldstr       "I'm ok"
        call        void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)        
        ret
    }
}
```

Comment: There are loopholes in the verifier built into the jitter, it doesn't catch everything.  You'll have to use connect.microsoft.com but they'll probably ignore it.

Comment: you don't want the jitter run PEVerify because it will failed for example in compiler generated classes and like Hans answer probably the jitter verifier has loopholes.